# Can I get sql server 2008 enterprise as a trial version for free?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I get sql server 2008 enterprise as a trial version for free?

specifically I want to get profiler (I want the profiler made my MS, not that open source version)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. 180 Day trial of SQL Server 2008 Enterprise is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need Enterprise; [Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/Developer.aspx) should be fine:

> SQL Server 2008 Developer includes all of the functionality of Enterprise Edition, but is licensed only for development, test, and demo use.

It's not free but [US$49](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-2008-Developer-Edition/product/C5EA00C9?WT.mc_id=productinfocenter) isn't a lot.